# php form not validatin or sending mails

Tags: php, forms, validation

I a trying to fix a php form that doesn't work
I am new to php, please help
I have the form in the index.html file and have another validation.php to validate the form fields.

```
<!-- contact form --->
<div class="containerq">
    <div class="form_container">
        <h2 class="text-center">Contact us</h2>
        <form action="index.php" method="post" class="rd-mailform">
            <input type="hidden" value="contact" name="form-type">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-prefix-1 col-md-12">
                        <label data-add-placeholder="" class="mfInput">
                            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-prefix-1 col-md-12">
                        <label data-add-placeholder="" class="mfInput">
                            <input type="text" name="email"  placeholder="Email">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-prefix-1 col-md-12">
                        <label data-add-placeholder="" class="mfInput">
                            <input type="text" name="phone"  placeholder="Phone">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-prefix-1 col-md-12">
                        <label data-add-placeholder="" class="mfSelect">
                            <select class="opt">
                                <option>Choose subject</option>
                                <option>I have a problem with a game</option>
                                <option>I have a problem with a course</option>
                                <option>I have an Idea</option>
                                <option>Collaboration with schools</option>
                                <option>Collaboration with game developers</option>
                                <option>General query and other subjects</option>                                   
                            </select>
                            <ul class="dropdown">
                                <li class="option">I have a problem with a game</li>
                                <li class="option">I have a problem with a course</li>
                                <li class="option">I have an Idea</li>
                                <li class="option">Collaboration with schools</li>
                                <li class="option">Collaboration with game developers</li>
                                <li class="option">General query and other subjects</li>
                            </ul><span class="mfPlaceHolder"></span>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-prefix-1 col-md-12">
                        <label data-add-placeholder="" class="mfInput">
                            <textarea data-constraints="" name="message" placeholder="Message" class="mtext"></textarea>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <!--<input class="header_button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Request">-->
                    <div class="header_button"><a href="#">Send Request</a>  </div>
                    <span class="success"><?php echo $successMessage;?></span>
                    <div class="mfInfo mfProgress"><span class="cnt"></span><span class="loader"></span><span class="msg"></span></div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

in the header (which is in included at the index.php start) I added:

```
<?php require_once "validation.php";?>
```

because if I put require_once validation.php at the start of the index the form wouldn't be accessed.

in the validation.php this is the part that sends the mail:

```
if( !($name=='') && !($email=='') && !($phone=='') &&!($message=='') )
    { // Checking valid email.
        if (preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email))
        {
            $header= $name."<". $email .">";
            $headers = "mywebsite.com"; /* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */
            $msg = "Hello! $name Thank you...! For Contacting Us.
            Name: $name
            E-mail: $email
            Phone: $phone
            Message: $message
            This is a Contact Confirmation mail. We Will contact You as soon as possible.";
            $msg1 = " $name Contacted Us. Hereis some information about $name.
            Name: $name
            E-mail: $email
            Phone: $phone
            Message: $message "; /* Send the message using mail() function */
            if(mail($email, $headers, $msg ) && mail("receiver_mail_id@mywebsite.com", $header, $msg1 ))
            {
                $successMessage = "Message sent successfully.......";
            }
        }
        else
        { 
            $emailError = "Invalid Email";
        }
    }
```

but id doesn't send anything
the page gets reloaded to index.php#
I don't get the invalid email or  Message sent successfully messages either

this is the complete validation.php:

```
<?php // Initialize variables to null.
//echo "validating";
$name =""; // Sender Name
$email =""; // Sender's email ID
$purpose =""; // Subject of mail
$message =""; // Sender's Message
$phone ="";
$nameError ="";
$emailError ="";
$phoneError ="";
$messageError ="";
$successMessage =""; // On submittingform below function will execute.
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ // Checking null values in message.
    echo "validating2";
    if (empty($_POST["name"])){
        $nameError = "Name is required";
    }
    else
    {
        $name = test_input($_POST["name"]); // check name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name))
        {
            $nameError = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        }
    } // Checking null values inthe message.
    if (empty($_POST["email"]))
    {
        $emailError = "Email is required";
    }
    else
    {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    } // Checking null values inmessage.
    if (empty($_POST["phone"]))
    {
        $phoneError = "Phone is required";
    }
    else
    {
        $phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
    } // Checking null values inmessage.
    if (empty($_POST["message"]))
    {
        $messageError = "Message is required";
    }
    else
    {
        $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
    } // Checking null values inthe message.
    if( !($name=='') && !($email=='') && !($phone=='') &&!($message=='') )
    { // Checking valid email.
        if (preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email))
        {
            $header= $name."<". $email .">";
            $headers = "mywebsite.com"; /* Let's prepare the message for the e-mail */
            $msg = "Hello! $name Thank you...! For Contacting Us.
            Name: $name
            E-mail: $email
            Phone: $phone
            Message: $message
            This is a Contact Confirmation mail. We Will contact You as soon as possible.";
            $msg1 = " $name Contacted Us. Here is some information about $name.
            Name: $name
            E-mail: $email
            Phone: $phone
            Message: $message "; /* Send the message using mail() function */
            if(mail($email, $headers, $msg ) && mail("contact@mywebsite.com", $header, $msg1 ))
            {
                $successMessage = "Message sent successfully.......";
            }
        }
        else
        { 
            $emailError = "Invalid Email";
        }
    }
} // Function for filtering input values.function test_input($data)
// Function for filtering input values.
function test_input($data)
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data =stripslashes($data);
    $data =htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
```

?>

any ideas?

Comment: so we should guess whats on validate.php?

Comment: Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: I see no POST arrays used anywhere and your `<select class="opt">` does not bear the name attribute for it, so we don't know if you're using that or not, or with JS.

Comment: `<!--<input class="header_button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Request">-->` why is that commented out? Oh never mind answering, you may have left for the day or wanting a magic answer. It's best to debug with error reporting, var_dump() and look at your HTML source. Good luck with this, really.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to make the post to long, I have no problem posting the whole validation.php

Comment: <!--<input class="header_button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Request">--> is commented out, because this something I've tried but didn't help, but I left it there so maybe I will need it later for a second try

Comment: You need to indicate in tag "action" the url of your validation page or include you validation php code in the same page. and uncomment the submit input type because you have $_POST["submit"] in your validation file. The name of your input will be the index of your POST tab.

Comment: Thanks Mathieu, I uncommented the submit input type andit works!!